# converting datetime.datetime object to datetime64[ns] in python for an netcdf file read with xarray module

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, netcdf, python-xarray

I have an netcdf file,I read it with xarray module.I want to make a plot from it. But the problem is the datatype of my time is datetime.datetime object and I am having problem with plotting. I want to change the datatype to datetime64. I tried using pandas pd.to_datetime and also using astype('datetime'). But I am having errors. I am displaying my errors below. Plz help me.
ds['time'] =  pd.to_datetime(ds['time'])    error:<class 'cftime._cftime.DatetimeNoLeap'> is not convertible to datetime

ds['time'] =  ds['time'].astype('datetime64')   error:Cannot cast datetime.datetime object from metadata [us] to  according to the rule 'same_kind'

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that the dates are not `datetime.datetime` objects; rather, they are `cftime.DatetimeNoLeap` objects, indicating that your data is indexed using times from a non-standard calendar.  Plotting times from a non-standard calendar can be enabled by installing the [nc-time-axis](https://github.com/SciTools/nc-time-axis) library.

If you'd still like to convert these objects to standard datetimes, that is possible -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55786995/converting-cftime-datetimejulian-to-datetime/55787899#55787899) -- but note that it will mean the dates used will no longer come from the same calendar as the underlying data.