# Is there a built-in way to convert datetimes to cftime in xarray?

Tags: python, datetime, python-xarray

I would like to plot two time series, one of which is in cftime and the other in datetime.

One possibility is to [convert cftime to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55786995/converting-cftime-datetimejulian-to-datetime), but this might give strange results for nonstandard cftime calendars (e.g. NoLeap). As such, I am trying to convert the datetime to cftime.

I can brute-force it as follows, but is there a built-in method available?

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import xarray as xr
>>>
>>> da = xr.DataArray(
...     [1, 2], coords={"time": pd.to_datetime(["2000-01-01", "2000-02-02"])}, dims=["time"]
... )
>>> print(da.time)
<xarray.DataArray 'time' (time: 2)>
array(['2000-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2000-02-02T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-02-02
>>>
>>>
>>> import cftime
>>>
>>>
>>> def datetime_to_cftime(dates, kwargs={}):
...     return [
...         cftime.datetime(
...             date.dt.year,
...             date.dt.month,
...             date.dt.day,
...             date.dt.hour,
...             date.dt.minute,
...             date.dt.second,
...             date.dt.microsecond,
...             **kwargs
...         )
...         for date in dates
...     ]
...
>>> datetime_to_cftime(da.time)
[cftime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, calendar='standard', has_year_zero=False), cftime.datetime(2000, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, calendar='standard', has_year_zero=False)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you might consider using [`DataArray.convert_calendar`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.convert_calendar.html#xarray.DataArray.convert_calendar).  For example if you would like to convert `datetime64` values to `cftime.DatetimeNoLeap` objects, you could do something like this:

```
>>> da.convert_calendar("noleap")
<xarray.DataArray (time: 2)>
array([1., 2.])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) object 2000-01-01 00:00:00 2000-02-02 00:00:00
```

This method is new as of xarray version 0.20.0.

Comment: Is there a good solution for versions older than that?